# Access header values calculated by node http server

Tags: node.js, http

Нello, please take a look at this simple file `server.js`:

```
require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('hiii');
  console.log('Response headers:', res.getHeaders());
}).listen(80);
```

Navigating to `localhost:80` in my browser hits this endpoint. This causes the response of `hiii` to appear in the browser, and also the headers to be logged to stdout.

The strange thing is, the headers logged to stdout disagree with the headers the browser received.

Stdout shows me an object representing 0 headers:

```
Response headers: [Object: null prototype] {}
```

Developer tools show me that in fact, 3 response headers were received:

[image: Connection: keep-alive; Content-length: 4; Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2020 18:29:51 GMT]

What accounts for this difference? I understand that the 3 headers shown in chrome are very fundamental to http. Is chrome receiving 0 headers, but filling them in by default? Is node's http library filling these headers in by default? If that's the case, why aren't they exposed via `res.getHeaders()`? Are these headers being calculated at some lower level, as in C libraries? If so is there any means of exposing these values?

I tried the following in case there is some kind of async delay where the headers are calculated:

```
require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('hiii');
  setTimeout(() => console.log('Response headers:', res.getHeaders()), 3000);
}).listen(80);
```

But nonetheless, 0 headers are sent to stdout.

**Somewhere, these 3 headers are being calculated! How can I access these calculated header values??**

Comment: If you ever follow `res.end()` in the debugger, you will see that it messes with the headers that it actually writes out without updating the stored headers.  That means it doesn't keep a record of exactly what it sent.  I don't think there's a way around this using the http library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found them under `res.socket._httpMessage._header`

```js
require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('HELLO', 'WORLD')
    res.end('hiii');
    console.log(res.getHeaders())
    console.log(res.socket._httpMessage._header)
}).listen(8000);
```

You can't get them using `getHeaders` because they are not set using the regular API but they are sent by nodejs internaly.

If you define a header yourself using `setHeader` then you'll be able to retrieve it using `getHeaders`

Response headers are not generated by the client since it needs them to be able to process the response. How can the client read the request if it doesn't know the size of the body (`Content-Length`).

These communication rules are defined in the [`HTTP RFC`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and the server must implement them so the client can understand the message it receives.

NodeJS calculates these information internaly ([source code exampe here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L777)) and probably sends them somehow in the socket without storing them in the high level API that you are using. ([another source code example](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js#L586))

Comment: It's worth noting that the end of http requests can be determined without `Content-Length` by waiting for the stream to end. There's also possibly some concern over using `_`-prefixed properties, as they could break in the future - but for my purposes now, this works great! :)